# Redirect command line into its own output?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-command-prompt

Windows CMD shell - any easy way of redirecting the command itself into the output? If I do net localgroup administrators > %computername%-admins.txt, I'd like the output file to contain the net statement as well.

No powershell available to me; pure CMD/COMMAND only.

This is for an audit; the auditors want to see what command generated the output. I'm trying to avoid screenshots or enormous copy-paste from CMD windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe kinda lame, but put the command in a batch file and redirect the output of the batch file to your txt file.

```
c:\echo net localgroup administrators > net_local_administrators.bat
c:\net_local_administrators.bat > %computername%-admins.txt
c:\del net_local_administrators.bat
```

Contents of %computername%-admins.txt (member names cleansed):

```
C:\>net localgroup administrators  
Alias name     administrators
Comment        Administrators have complete and unrestricted access to the computer/domain

Members

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator
MYDomain\Domain Admins
User1
User2
The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: That shows the batch file name, which is not guaranteed to match the contents. This is for an audit; the auditors want to see what command generated the output. I'm trying to avoid screenshots or enormous copy-paste from CMD windows.

Comment: I get the full command prompt with the command in the .txt file

Comment: Ooh - nice. Got it.

Comment: Works for me. Ugly-ish workaround, but I'll take it

Comment: Gives the auditors something to weed through.